# Setting the authenticated user context for an API?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insights to gather telemetry for an API. Only authenticated clients (like a mobile app) can access the resources of the API. This is using the OAuth2 client credentials flow. There are no users in the system.

Would it make sense to set `client_id` (which actually doesn't represent a user but rather an "authenticated application or device") to the `AuthenticatedUserId` value in the user context?

Currently we are storing the `client_id` as a custom field, but I've just discovered that there is a "user" section that is sent within the context of telemetry.

```
public class ClientIdTelemetryInitialiser : TelemetryInitializerBase
{
    public ClientIdTelemetryInitialiser(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) 
        : base(contextAccessor)
    { }

    protected override void OnInitializeTelemetry(
            HttpContext platformContext,
            RequestTelemetry rootRequestTelemetry,
            ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var claims = platformContext.User.Claims;
        var clientId = claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("client_id", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        // Old way of doing it
        rootRequestTelemetry.Context.Properties["client_id"] = clientId.Value;

        // New way of doing it??
        rootRequestTelemetry.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId = clientId.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `context.user` id fields to use whatever kind of id you want.

if you use those fields, some of the "user" based charts in the portal *should* light up for you if they weren't showing anything before.

there's also a user.AnonymousId that you could use for tracking things prior to a user becoming authenticated, if there were such a thing.